# Bootstrap pagination without giving link but fetching data dynamically

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, pagination

This is what bootstrap does.

```
<ul class="pagination">
  <li><a href="#">&laquo;</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">1</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">2</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">3</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">4</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">5</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">&raquo;</a></li>
</ul>
```

They give link to each page.

What should I do if I don't have data as pages but need to fetch contents from a db on user clicking the next page?

How to replace those links if the fetched data is an array not pages?

Please suggest me. I am doing pagination for the first time.

Comment: You know the difference between client and server side, right? Bootstrap (HTML) has nothing to do with DB actually. You need server-side language between them.

Comment: how to replace those links if the data got is an array?

Comment: What array? JavaScript, PHP, or what? Where do you have you data fetched from DB?

Comment: So this is not about twitter at all. It's all about AngularJS. Provide proper JS code that you've tried, then we will try to help.

Answer (score 0):

I would do an onclick event.. make a call using [AJAX](http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_database.asp) and then return my data and populate the page...You may want to consider returning your data into [JSON](http://www.json.org/) format and then populating the page...

You may also want to learn about some basics before you dive into this adventure.

[Client Side VS Server Side & languages](http://www.codeconquest.com/website/client-side-vs-server-side/)

Comment: how to replace those links if the data got is an array? Thats my question.